# Django Factory Boy object does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django, pytest, factory-boy

I have an issue regarding factory boy using in the testing of my Lets assume I have this three models:

```
Class Company(models.Model):
   name = str

Class Domain(models.Model):
   company = ForeignKey(ref=Company)
   name = str
   created_at = datetime

Class Record(models.Model):
   domain = ForeignKey(ref=Domain)
   name = str
   created_at = datetime

CompanyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
   name = str

DomainFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
   company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
   name = str
   created_at = datetime

RecordFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
   domain = factory.SubFactory(DomainFactory)
   name = str
   created_at = datetime
```

Having this, when I'm testing the `Record` views, at the begginning of every view I check that the `Domain` object is, in fact, related to the `Company` object such as:

```
try:
  domain = Domain.objects.get(domain=domain_id, company__id=company_id)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
   return Response(
            data={"message": "Domain isn't related to the company provided."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )
```

But this code always returns an ObjectDoesNotExist exception when I make the testing with pytest+factory-boy but when I do manual testing runs fine. Have you experienced something similar? What I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

As requested per @gbrennon I'm adding the test code:

```
Hi! Thanks for answering.
```

My test code is as it follows:

```
class RecordCompanyAdminTests(CompanyAdminUser):
    
    def setUp(self):
        super(RecordCompanyAdminTests, self).setUp()
        self.domain = DomainFactory.create()
        self.record = RecordFactory.create()
        
    def test_record_list_get(self):
        url = reverse("autoprovisioning:record_list", kwargs={"company_id": self.company.id, "domain_id": self.domain.id})
        
        response = self.client.get(url, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

how are u doing?

the test code wasn't included but i'll try to infer things

- `when I do manual testing runs fine`

it seems like u already populated ur database! but listen, when u run ur test suite django will be using a "test database" in favor of isolation!

what u need to do is to create, using the `factory_boy` lib, ur "data fixtures"!

my suggestion without any context:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.existing_domain_in_database = DomainFactory.create(...) # insert here the data to populate this model
```

and the desired data should already exists in ur "test database" for every test that is going to be run inside of this class

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question providing futher information about the test code. But to me it seems that i'm already doing this. Please check the updated question when you can.

Comment: ok, where are u defining this `self.company.id`?

Comment: Actually I found out I was passing `self.company.id` and not `self.domain.company.id` to the url so that's why the object wasn't found. Right now I have another problem as I have a Permissions system checking the groups the user belongs to. 
I'm trying to select a concrete `Company` to use it as a `SubFactory` in my `DomainFactory`.  Do you have any suggestions. Thanks again, you were very helpful.